# Find partly duplicates in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list like this :

```
my_list =
    [
    {'name': 'avg', 'indexes': [3]}, 
    {'name': 'sma', 'indexes': [2, 3]}
    ]
```

I would like to **efficiently** find all dicts where `indexes` keys that has 1 item, and it exists in another dict that has 2, and remove it. ( here `[3]` is in `[2,3]` )

Basically find duplicates and remove the *shorter* list.

In this case for instance, remove : `{'name': 'avg', 'indexes': [3]}` ,  and we usually might have multiple of them.

The `indexes` array can be in length `1` or `>1`, we want to check if `len(dic)=1` is inside a dic with a `len(dic)` > 1

Comment: Why would a lambda be faster? What have you tried and was it actually slow?

Comment: You need to be clear about the use-case here. For example, what if an *indexes* list has more than 2 elements. How will you handle that? Also, what makes you think that *lambda* is more appropriate than any other approach?

Comment: thanks, i removed this requirement, what i did is first to find all dics with a single item, then check for each if its in the other one, which seems ugly.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks olvin, i am editing, but in general , it's 1 or >1..

Comment: @baltiturg >1? So could be thousands?

Comment: could be but usually less than 10. Sorry i am not very clear, just looking for a simple solution.

Comment: You can do a 2-pass filtering, first collecting all items from more-than-2-indices to a ``set`` and then removing all items from only-1-index that are in the ``set``.

Comment: @baltiturg OK - So now please show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks, if you can show how, it would be great and i will accept.

Comment: Are you just trying to find duplicates for your `indexes` in the dictionaries and remove them?

Comment: @BattleCalls yes, and if so remove the duplicates which has less items in the dic

Comment: Am I missing something or do you not always need a list name to play with it? Your list doesn't have a name so you can't refer to it.

Comment: yes it has a name of course, otherwise its not a valid python, i thought its clear, i edited it.

Comment: Is your requirement simplied like to find all indexes of a particular name in a single dict entry

Comment: I think your requirements are not clear: what if your list is like:            [
    {'name': 'avg', 'indexes': [1, 6]}, 
    {'name': 'sma', 'indexes': [2, 3, 4]},

    {'name': 'foo', 'indexes': [1, 4, 7]},
    
    ]

would you remove avg because it contains 1 and is shorter than foo, or keep it because it is the only one containing 6?

Answer (score 0):

First collect all indexes from lists with multiple indexes, then use that to filter:

```
my_list = [
    {'name': 'avg', 'indexes': [3]}, 
    {'name': 'sma', 'indexes': [2, 3]}
]

remove = {x
          for d in my_list
          if len(d['indexes']) > 1
          for x in d['indexes']}

my_list = [d
           for d in my_list
           if len(d['indexes']) != 1
           or d['indexes'][0] not in remove]

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Hi, what's about if you got duplicate indexes, should you remove them either ?

Comment: @baskettaz Do you mean if there were a list like `[2, 2]`? They're just talking about the lengths of the lists, and that is larger than 1 in that case.

Comment: No, i meant recurent indexes - lists for example, something like this :          
     {'name': 'avg',  'indexes': [3]},
    {'name': 'sma1', 'indexes': [5, 6,100]},
    {'name': 'sma2', 'indexes': [5, 6,100]}, should we take only the first one or all will be interesting ? This is actualy a question to @baltiturg ? :)

Comment: @baskettaz None of those shall be removed. The one with `[3]` shall not be removed because `3` isn't contained in a longer list, and those with `[5, 6,100]` shall not be removed because only those with lists of length 1 shall be removed.

Comment: @baskettaz Oh and if it's a question to baltiturg, then you should ask that under the question, not here.

Comment: My lecture on *Basically find duplicates and remove the shorter list.*  is somehow different :)

Comment: @baskettaz Yeah, that's a vague statement, but then they specified it more precisely: *"we want to check if len(dic)=1 is inside a dic with a len(dic) > 1"*.